# Is it safe to delete the Windows_Old folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows 7 machine, which I upgraded from Vista when I first got it.  After I upgraded it I left the `Windows_Old` folder there.  Later, I got into the registry to see if anything in the registry was pointing to something under that `Windows_Old` folder location, and I was surprised to see that there was.

I had heard that once you upgrade from an older version of Windows to a newer one, you could safely delete the `Windows_Old` folder, but I'm concerned about this. Why would there be anything pointing to a defunct system directory?  May I delete `Windows_Old` to free up space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this (and ensure that its safe) is by using window's Disk Cleanup. Run disk cleanup and select the option that says previous windows installations.

From [Microsoft answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/can-i-delete-windowsold-file-after-installing/4c48dbe7-2830-4df8-905b-086f6cbd9159)

I found that thread from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-remove-the-Windows-old-folder).

Comment: This is what I had to do, worked fine